# DIV wrapping on browser resize

Tags: css, html, css-float, resize

So basically the website I'm designing has 3 divs inside a container div. One floating to the left. Two to the right one above and one below. They work fine when the browser is maximized. Problem is, when the browser is resized, the right divs wrap below the left div even though I've set min-widths. I want the divs to remain where they are and a scroll bar to appear instead. I did try overflow, no luck. Any solutions?

PS- Initially I had added min-width for the inner divs too. They didn't seem to solve the problem, so I removed them.
A solution or a nudge in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Here's a link to the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/R62w4/3/

Thank you, Matthew. Although that fixed the wrapping issue, my site now has a thin line of pixels on the right hand side. Any idea how I remove it? It continues from the header till the footer. It isn't affected by any changes to the CSS elements pertaining to the header or navigation bar or footer.

Okay, I found the reason to the extra space on the right side. If  I increase my margins for the outer div, the space increases. Is there a way to increase the margins without getting a space?

Comment: Tried putting the three divs in a wrapper that has a min-width? If that doesn't work, try the wrapper with a min-width and white-space:nowrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to wrap them in this:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">

</div>
```

... to prevent that from happening.

It's hard to know exactly where the problem is, could you post some code or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

**Update:**

I believe the problem is that you are using % based widths and px for margins - it's easy to lose track of how much available space you have and subsequently your layout falls apart. Consider that two left floated DIVs of 50% width with 1px of margin each will break on to two lines every time because that's more than 100%.

I changed your fiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/R62w4/5/

... just by moving the left margin from your first DIV and right margin from your other two to the parent container seems to give enough room for everything.

P.S. You *can* use % based margins and just make sure everything you want to be on one line stays <= 100%.

Comment: @MetalFrog Just noticed your comment had the possible solution. Why not turn yours into an answer and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

the [simpl css framework](http://simpl.romack.net/) shows you how to do percentage based columns with pixel based margins which is what you want.